# EB CLI doesn't initialize EB repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I want to initialize an EB repository with this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html)
I run the init command

```
eb init -p python 3.8 myappname --region eu-west-3
```

it returns this message

```
usage: eb init <application_name> [options ...]
eb: error: unrecognized arguments: myappname
```

Comment: It should be `eb init -p python-3.8 myappname --region eu-west-3`

Comment: I think we've written the same commands.

Comment: No, you have a typo in your command. You have `python 3.8`, it should be `python-3.8`